# STM32F769DISCO + wireless connectivity using ESP8266

Tags: embedded, esp8266, wireless

I am working on a project with a STM32F769Discovery board and I don't have much experience with embedded C programming. I have the following items which I would like to get working together:

- STM32F769 with small round LCD screen (+ microSDcard reader, ESP8266 
  module)
- A nodeMCU ESP8266 controller

So far I can display images or animations on the LCD screen with the use of the emWin graphical library. And now what I want to achieve is to find a way to wirelessly (either via Bluetooth or Wi-Fi) send a image file to the STM32 board for it to display on the LCD screen. Preferably from a central gateway/hub to the STM with the LCD display. I read some things about using two microcontrollers together using a protocol like UART, SPI or I2c but I don't know where to start just yet.
[Small scheme of how I would want it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WPHq.png)

I am looking for any tips or advice in general on what approach I should take. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest possible solution would probably be to buy a Bluetooth <--> UART module and connect the UART pins to the STM32.

Buy a Bluetooth dongle (if your PC does not already have Bluetooth) and write a program in a language of your choice that:

1. Reads an image file of the file format that you expect to receive on the STM32 side
2. Splits the image data into appropriate chunks
3. Connects to the Bluetooth <--> UART module (over Bluetooth)
4. Sends the chunks one by one

On the STM32 side you need to implement an UART driver to communicate with the Bluetooth <--> UART module and either buffer the entire image until fully received or stream the data directly to the display if possible.